# Get parent class from child class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a method that accepts a single parameter.  That parameter can be any class A, B, C, or D that all inherit from the same parent class E.  I do not know the name of the parent class, however (maybe it's "E" maybe it's "F").

I want my method to accept as a parameter the parent class, so I can pass in a child object (so I only need one implementation of the method).

How do I find the name of the parent class?  It is in a jar that I do not have source code access to.

**EDIT**

Example of what method will look like:

```
private void processResults(final ???parentClassName??? aParentClassName) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: decompile it or `instanceof` check or let IDE or some other tool provide information about that class to you using assist functions

Comment: It would be great if you can share some code. What is method signature. either it accepts E or F?

Comment: If I decompiled I would only see the logic flow, correct?  I did not think decompiling reserves the original names.

Comment: I think there should be two overloaded methods that accepts E or F.

Comment: @Braj OP says s/he doesn't have source

Comment: @Braj I do not know what it accepts.  That is why I am asking the question.

Comment: In Java, you can call getClass() on any object to get a Class object describing it. Is this what you wanted? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29

Comment: What you know? Share some sample code if possible.

Comment: @Braj I have shared sample code.  As you can see, I don't know the name of the parent class.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Decompiling should preserve exact class names. If you have access to the Javadocs, the parent class should be mentioned there as well.

Comment: How does it make sense to have a common implementation for argument types A, B, C, and D when the nature of the relationship between those types is uncertain?  A suitable method signature is the least of the problems to tackle here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the relationship between those types is not uncertain. It is known to the author of the library; it is simply not known (yet) to Soylent Green.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Perhaps I wasn't clear in the question - A, B, C, and D will ALL either inherit from E or ALL inherit from F.  No mixing.  My problem is that I don't know whether it's E or F.  I have edited my question slightly to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) tool that comes with the JDK.

Suppose your jar file is named `unknown.jar` and that the package for class `A` whose parent class you are interested in is `com.example.unknown`.

You can do this:

```
javap -classpath unknown.jar com.example.unknown.A
```

And the output will be something like:

```
Compiled from "A.java"
public class com.example.unknown.A extends com.example.unknown.E {
  public com.example.unknown.A();
}
```

It will also show you the public API of `A`. It can show you more information, too, depending on the command line parameters you pass. Use `javap -help` to see them all.

(Note: You may need to specify additional jars or directories to the `-classpath` parameter, if `unknown.jar` has other dependencies.)

Comment: Perfect.  This is just what I needed.  I can check without putting my code into runtime to see results of code Braj suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Class#getSuperclass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29)

> Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> - If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned.
> - If this object represents an array class then the Class object representing the Object class is returned.

sample code:

```
A.class.getSuperclass().getName()
```

or

```
aObject.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()
```

Comment: I think this is what i needed... I'm testing now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the superclass / the name of the superclass it's impossible, I think.

If there are only 4 classes, why don't you just create an interface and let your classes A to D inherit them? Might be easier :)